# self taught -syntax error i can find- this query works in my system but no embedded in excel to same database

Tags: excel

new to this (very new- and self teaching).....i have a query that draws from multiple tables on my computer system that gets all the appraised values and sales values from a subdivision. in my system, it runs the query fine. but when i try to convert it to run embedded in an excel sheet it gives me error saying no column name for 2 c and 3 c. when i put punctuation around the column names it says there is a syntax error with the alias "as c" at the bottom-- been awake too long--- what am i doing wrong ?:

```
select distinct pv.prop_id, ac.file_as_name,
'sale_type' , 'deed_date' , 'sale_date' , 'sale_type' , 'sale_price' ,
(pv.land_hstd_val + pv.land_non_hstd_val + pv.ag_market + pv.timber_market)as land_val,
(pv.imprv_hstd_val + pv.imprv_non_hstd_val)as imprv_val,
pv.market, pv.abs_subdv_cd
from property_val pv with (nolock)
inner join prop_supp_assoc psa with (nolock) on
   pv.prop_id = psa.prop_id
   and pv.prop_val_yr = psa.owner_tax_yr
   and pv.sup_num = psa.sup_num
inner join property p with (nolock) on
   pv.prop_id = p.prop_id
inner join owner o with (nolock) on
   pv.prop_id = o.prop_id
   and pv.prop_val_yr = o.owner_tax_yr
   and pv.sup_num = o.sup_num
inner join account ac with (nolock) on
   o.owner_id = ac.acct_id
left outer join
   (select cop.prop_id,
    convert(varchar(20), co.deed_dt, 101)as deed_date,
    convert(varchar(20), s.sl_dt, 101)as sale_date,
    s.sl_price as sale_price, s.sl_type_cd as sale_type
          from chg_of_owner_prop_assoc cop with (nolock)
          inner join chg_of_owner co with (nolock) on
                 co.chg_of_owner_id = cop.chg_of_owner_id
          inner join sale s with (nolock) on
                 co.chg_of_owner_id = s.chg_of_owner_id
          where cop.seq_num = 0) as c
          on c.prop_id = pv.prop_id
where pv.prop_val_yr = 2016
and(pv.prop_inactive_dt is null or udi_parent ='t')
and pv.abs_subdv_cd in('s3579')
order by pv.abs_subdv_cd, pv.prop_id
```

Comment: when you say in your system, what do you mean?

Comment: I have a data base system called pacs. It's a multi state appraisal software

Comment: how does excel connect to this database? or is the data in the spreadsheet?

Comment: Embedded sql. Thru 'connections' in the spreadsheet. Connects directly to database thru ms query editor. I just paste in my query from a query designer in the database program. But the query designer is very cumbersome and using excel query editor is tons faster and easier to share.

Comment: using the brackets was the perfect answer ! Thank you guys so much !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it SQL Server? Try surrounding column names with square brackets instead of quotes.

Comment: this should surely be a comment?

Comment: Yeah? I felt as if it offered a potential solution so would be best placed as an answer?

Comment: It is, but it still matters what RDBMS is being used for syntactical purposes.